# Using CakePHP How do I export data from the database. Not including the schema

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

In my CakePHP App, I have exported my database schema, however now I just need the data that I will use to pre-populate for the user.

Will not work as it generates only the schema:

```
cake schema generate
```

Looking for a solution that will generate an Insert or Update of current data in the db.

**Update:**

This is for an installer that I am writing. When a user completes the installation it should populate the db with data required for the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** The OP is not asking how to get data from the database command line per se. He wants to create an installer that will populate a database when the user runs the installation. For example, when you install WordPress, you are not going to run mysqldump, right? The application takes care of it. This is a similar situation.

The easiest way to do this is to use the models that come with the application.

Check to see if the system is installed, if not run the following:

1. open the installer asking for the DB credentials in a form
2. use the credentials to create the database
3. if the database cannot be created, explain that they must create the
   database manually
4. save the credentials to the correct location in the database.php
   config
5. create the schema from within the controller
6. once the schema is built, load all of the pre-set data from the
   model

Take advantage of the install controller / db models within cake to do the lifting. So for example, if you want to pre-load some configuration settings:

```
$config['Config']['setting_1'] = 'foo';
$config['Config']['setting_2'] = 'bar';

$this->loadModel('Config');
$this->Config->create();
$this->Config->save($config);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Use MySQL to do this:

```
mysqldump -u <username> -p <databasename>
```

Replace  and  with your username and database names.

Comment: Mysql dump is an answer. However it is not the answer I am looking for.

Comment: 1) It's destructive: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ep_options`;

2) My Schema command already creates my tables. I am just looking to populate them

3) They include the table prefix, which could vary depending on the installation.

Comment: all you have between your hand is in the option of `cake schema` command - and in your ask : "Looking for a solution that will generate an Insert or Update of current data in the db." no chance to see the UPDATE - how cake / the DBMS could know when an update have to be done ? so I think like @predominant that `mysqldump` with `--no-create-info` will dump the data without the `create table`  - regards

Comment: 4) What happens when I branch out to different DBMS? mysqldump is no longer valid.